# How to specify a custom amazon machine image(AMI) ID when creating elastic beanstalk environments with CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've learned how to use custom AMI ID with Elastic Beanstalk Console from this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html).

How can I do the same thing with `aws elasticbeanstalk` or `eb` commands?

I couldn't find how to do it from [AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html#cli-aws-elasticbeanstalk).

And I feel like that the `PlatformArn` value in the saved configuration file must be changed if I want to use a custom AMI ID.

Any knows how to specify custom AMI ID with command lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specify the AMI ID you will need to manage more of your Beanstalk environment. While you are getting started with these features, I recommend that you start using an existing AMI that works with Beanstalk (pick one that you have already tested).

The key is that the AMI ID is part of the `launch configuration`.

CLI:

`aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment --region us-west-2 --application-name my-app --environment-name my-env --version-label v1 --solution-stack-name "64bit Windows Server 2016 v1.2.0 running IIS 10.0" --option-settings Namespace=aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration,OptionName=ImageId,Value="ami-xxxxxxx"`

SDK:

You can specify the AMI ID via the `OptionSettings` in the createEnvironment() call.

Sample code:

```
var var params = {
  ApplicationName: "my-app", 
  CNAMEPrefix: "my-app", 
  EnvironmentName: "my-env", 
  SolutionStackName: "64bit Windows Server 2016 v1.2.0 running IIS 10.0", 
  VersionLabel: "v1",
  OptionSettings: [
    {
      Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
      OptionName: 'ImageId',
      Value: 'ami-xxxxxxx'
    },
  ],
 };
 elasticbeanstalk.createEnvironment(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

This article discusses the above methods in detail:

[Using a custom AMI with Elastic Beanstalk](https://incarnated.net/blog/using-a-custom-ami-with-elastic-beanstalk/)

Comment: If my desired `environment type` is `single instance` instead of `load balancing, auto scaling`, how can I set AMI ID?

Comment: The AMI Id is specified in `aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration` for single instance also. This is also where the EC2 Instance Type can be set. This is called a Beanstalk NameSpace. AWS has good documentation for this.

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious about why EB configurations could be found in `.ebextensions`, saved configuration, and `--option-settings`. This makes me confused. 
Why don't the designers of EB put all the configurations in one place?

Comment: Please open a new question. Long comment threads are not good.